# iOS: Keychain item not syncing with iCloud with kSecAttrSynchronizable as String : kCFBooleanTrue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, icloud

I am trying to sync item to iCloud, but its storing in local device only.
When i try to fetch value for same keychain item on other simulator, its not retrieving from iCloud.

I am doing this testing on two simulators.

This is the query i am using to save item -

```
[kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword as String,
kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
kSecValueData as String: data,
kSecAttrSynchronizable as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
kSecAttrAccessGroup as String : group
```

I tried with Featutes -> Trigger iCloud sync. but not working
same iCloud account is configured on both simulator. and Keychain sharing is on for the account.

Please help if any one have any idea..

Comment: Have you figured this out in the end? I also can't get the syncing to work on the simulator, however it seems to work between two physical devices logged in with the same Apple ID

Comment: Yes, it does not work on simulator. it works only on physical device with same apple id login